# Devo utilizar Em em todo lugar ou somente em Fontes?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Sei que se deve usar *em* ao invés de *px* em fontes para um bom desempenho da sua aplicação em celulares, porém só uso isso em tamanho de fontes.
Devo usar *em* também em lugares como margens, paddings, line-height, etc?
Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com o @Ricardo Mota nessa, acho que você vai acabar mais tempo fazendo cálculos do que realmente fazendo um site bom. Na minha pratica para height, width uso porcentagem para facilitar nos cálculos e em só uso  em fontes mesmo, porém antes de usa-los geralmente deixo eles equivalente a 10px , também para facilitar no cálculo. Recomendo se tiver mais duvidas sobre tal prática de uso de EM vistar esse artigo http://clagnut.com/blog/348/ está em inglês porém ajuda bastante. Ou esse artigo do tableless http://tableless.com.br/unidade-pixels-em-rem/ .
Valeu

Answer (score 2):

*em* é usado em fontes para ajudar na responsividade. Se você for trabalhar com *em* esteja preparado para perder tempo com cálculos.
Muitos sites padronizam os tamanhos de fontes em pixel como globo e uol.
Essa matéria do tableless pode ajudá-lo 
http://tableless.com.br/unidade-pixels-em-rem/

Answer (score 1):

**O que é EM?**

1 EM era originalmente correspondente ao tamanho da letra M maiúscula de uma determinada fonte. Já no CSS, 1 EM é correspondente ao valor de font-size, que, por padrão do browser é em média 16px.

Então partindo da definição geral de EM, ela é ideal para fontes. Já para outras medidas, como tamanho de divs, etc, transforme os pixels em %.

**Como fazer isso?**

```
objeto : contexto = resultado.
```

Exemplo: Uma coluna de 264px dentro de uma div de 1128px de largura.

Você pega 264 e divide por 1128, que dará 0,23404255319149. Mexa a virgula duas pra direita e temos a porcentagem:23.404255319149%.  Pode usar sem arredondar mesmo para maior perfeição.

Apesar de assim se usar maior quantidade de cálculos, acredito que o resultado é muito mais satisfatório caso deseje um site realmente responsivo.